# Customization YCommerceWebService - Webroot "/rest" not working anymore

Tags: rest, web-services, customization, sap-commerce-cloud

I created a YcommerceWebServices with "ant extgen", added it in localextension file, I added the oAuth2 authentification extension.
When I was doing request from postam like :
    https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{baseSiteID}/users/{userID}/...
It was working, I was receiving all the information. Since I started to customize I get all the time HTTP Error 302 Moved temporarily .
Even when I am on the hac and I click on my customExtension in the column web on "/rest"[image] I get a 404 (before it was working too)
I tried to "Ant clean all" and update from Hac, no result.

Comment: did you check the filter in commercewebservices in debug

Comment: @TylerI Are you talking about /webroot/WEB-INF/config/v2/filer-config-v2-spring.xml ?          If yes, I didn't change anything in this file

Comment: yes but depending on the filter list, could you please try debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the fact, that during my customization by modifying the file /web/webroot/WEB-INF/config/v2/dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml
I had made an error on the declaration of a bean.

Indeed looking carefully at the compilation and launch of the server (ant clean all - ./hybrisserver.sh). I saw that there was an error. the launcher was launched but my webservice was not active.